# AOSP build with AndroidTv launcher HD resolution

Tags: java, android, android-source, television

I have build AOSP for Lollipop (Android 5.0.1, emulator), but I don't get the TV launcher when I run the emulator, and I need to set the resolution to HD and the layout to landscape.

I search but I didn't find anything useful.

What am I missing? Can someone point me to a relevant resource?